# JavaScript to HTML Value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying get a jsquery for the email to post in an HTML value box, it is the only way that the form will send with the relevant info that I need.

```
$(function () {
    var email = GetParameterValues('email');
    var id = GetParameterValues('userid');
    $('#spn_email').html('<strong>' + email + '</strong>');
    $('#spn_UserId').html('<strong>' + id + '</strong>');
    $("#email").val(email)
});

function GetParameterValues(param) {
    var url = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
    for (var i = 0; i < url.length; i++) {
        var urlparam = url[i].split('=');
        if (urlparam[0] == param) {
            return urlparam[1];
        }
    }
}
```

Is pulling the query from URL, it needs to go into.

```
<label class="">
    <span class="fieldLabel">Email</span><span class="gaq-required asterisk" aria-hidden="true">*</span>
    <input type="text" name="contact:email" value="" maxlength="50" aria-required="true">
</label>
```

In the value="" field.

Comment: you don't have any element with an ID of 'email'

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `GetParameterValues` function is working, you have not properly assigned an ID to your email `input`. Because you wrote `$("#email").val(email)`, your input field should read:

```
<input type="text" id="email" name="contact:email" value="" maxlength="50" aria-required="true">
```

Notice the `id` attribute. That corresponds with the "#" symbol.

If you can't edit the input field, you can target the field by name, doing something like:

`$('input[name=contact:email]').val(email)`

Comment: The second part can not be changed. It only pushes through the back end like it is written. How can I change the javascript to change that?

Comment: You will have to target that field by name. I'll update my post.

Comment: Where does that get put in the grand scheme of things?

Comment: Replace `$("#email").val(email)` with `$('input[name=contact:email]').val(email)`

Comment: Still doesn't populate the field

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to do

```
$('input[name=contact:email]').attr('value', email)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try enclosing the jQuery selector name selector and set the value to `email`. It will not work unless you put a different type of quotation than the first outer quotes:

```
$("input[name='contact:email']").val(email);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/nfgL9hm3/

Comment: I have edited that, but it still is not coming through in the value field. Is there something that I am missing on that side? I know that the Javascript is pulling what I need it to, just getting it into that field.

Comment: I've tested all the code that you presented with the change I write above and it works successfully. There error must be in another part of your code. Does your console report any errors?

Comment: No, and Im using brackets

Comment: @JonathanYates, I don't understand what you mean about brackets?? If you change `$("#email").val(email)` in your code with what I provided, I have tested, and it does solve the problem in my test environment

Comment: Brackets is the console I'm working in. It is to pull the query at the end of the URL into the value field. But when I put a query string in the URL it does not pull anything to the text box.

Comment: Brackets is your editor, but the console error I was looking for would be a browser. Send me a Jfiddle with the code in question. There must be a bug in there somewhere else

Comment: Might be missing something here but it isnt working on my end. Although the code does function, it does not do what I need it to do. I need it to post in the value field from the url.

Comment: I am now assuming that you are typing the `?email=xxx` into the url of the fiddle which will not work because it runs in an iframe. You need to use the code presented in a separate html file. I can confirmed that this works. There isn't anything else I can answer...

Comment: I have posted this code to a site and it does not push through. I don't use fiddle, I am posting to a live workstation.

Comment: ErrorNotification.js:125 ConsoleAgent: Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined (url: http://127.0.0.1:1230/index.html?email=jonathanbrianyates@gmail.com) in :8ErrorNotification.js:125 window.console.error/LiveDevelopment/Agents/ConsoleAgent.js:55 _log/LiveDevelopment/Agents/ConsoleAgent.js:62 _onMessageAdded/utils/EventDispatcher.js:222 trigger/utils/EventDispatcher.js:260 triggerWithArray/LiveDevelopment/Inspector/Inspector.js:228 _onMessage

Gives me this error on this line

  return _consoleError.apply(window.console, arguments);